# calling a function in dplyr pipes - best approach

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am reading the book **R for data science** (https://r4ds.had.co.nz/model-basics.html). In the chapter on models I see the following code:

```
    models <- tibble(
      a1 = runif(250, -20, 40),
      a2 = runif(250, -5, 5)
    )
    
    model1 <- function(a, data) {
      a[1] + data$x * a[2]
    }


    sim1 <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 10L, 10L), y = c(4.2, 7.51, 2.13, 8.99, 10.24, 11.3, 
7.36, 10.51, 10.51, 12.43, 11.89, 14.26, 19.13, 11.74, 16.02, 
13.27, 15.96, 16.89, 20.09, 17.17, 19.94, 21.73, 18.39, 22.48, 
26.78, 22.81, 21.13, 24.97, 23.35, 21.98)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L))   # rounded values from modelr::sim1 from modelr 0.1.8



    measure_distance <- function(mod, data) {
      diff <- data$y - model1(mod, data)
      sqrt(mean(diff^2))
    }
    
    sim1_dist <- function(a1, a2) {
      measure_distance(c(a1,a2), sim1)
    }
```

Here sim1 is a dataset of x, y values which is close to being linearly related.
In order to compute the distance between models and actual data, the book proposes:

```
    models %>%
      mutate(dist = purrr::map2_dbl(a1, a2, sim1_dist))
```

I want to know how is it different from (which gives the same result).

```
    models %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(dist = sim1_dist(a1, a2))
```

There are different approaches to solve the same problem. Just want to know why we would prefer one over the other.

Also, even if I don't use rowwise, the answer does not change. Why? Shouldn't the arguments (a1, a2) sent to sim1_dist be row by row?

Thank you.

Comment: There are a lot of considerations here - one might be that if you call `rowwise()`, you will also need to `ungroup()` to revert `rowwise()`. This makes the initial code using `purrr` more efficient from a wordcount perspective.

Comment: When I take out `rowwise()`, the result does change, becoming `dist  81.6` for all rows. using dplyr 1.0.4

Comment: You are correct @JonSpring. The result does change. I was doing it incorrectly.

Comment: @Matt: I agree, I will need to ungroup() and hence the solution in the book might be better. Just wanted to confirm. Because, the solution that is more intuitive to me was the later one.

Comment: The rowwise solution has fewer dependencies (i.e. purrr not used) although it would be possible to get rid of all dependencies using  `transform(models, dist = mapply(sim1_dist, a1, a2))`